# Hosting WCF Service Application with Plesk Panel 9.2

Tags: wcf, plesk

Is there a way to host wcf service application with Plesk Panel 9.2 in shared hosting under Windows 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't depend on Plesk but on the actual server you are controling using Plesk. If it has the .NET framework 3 or later installed you can host WCF services. However if you only have .NET 2 you can't. Please keep in mind that the .NET framework version reported is 2 even if 3.0 or later is installed as that is the version of the CLR which hasn't changes since.